# how to fix CORS problem in node and react app with socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Hello we are trying to implment a Chat feature in our already working applicaiton which is a MERN stack app,
we opted to use socket.io because its fairly easy to set up and use,we managed to get it working locally but when we deployed on our dev server the chat wasn't working , we followed this socket.io document to try and solve the problem which served us well when we had the CORS problem locally , https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/
this is the server side code used :

```
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "<client web address>",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
```

this on its own didn't work on the server but it was enough to get it to work locally where we put localhost:3000 there instead.

```
 const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
      cors: {
        origin: "http/localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      },
```

so we added this on the client side , instead of having

```
 socket = io(":5000")
```

when we are defining the socket we changed it to

```
socket = io("<server_ip_addresse>:5000");
```

> GET
> http://************:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbhodkH
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

this is the error we are getting when the component responsible for the chat is trying to set up a socket with the server

how can we solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to use the website URL in both settings; for the cors origin address in the backend and for the socket creating in the front end
so

```
  const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
      cors: {
        origin: "<website URL>",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      },
```

and when setting up the socket with the server from the client we used used the same URL on which our app was deployed in the dev server

so like this without any ports what so ever

```
socket = io("<website URL>");
```